# Inverting the order of integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$\int_0^2 \int_{y/2}^1 y\cos(x^3 - 1) dxdy$

For this problem, I need to invert the integral so I can evaluate it.

I have NO idea where to start this. Usually, as a first instinct I'll get the 2D graph of the function, but this does not help me, at all.

I've been trying to find step by step solutions for inverting integrals but they're all with examples of super simple ones. None like these...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Draw a picture of the region of integration and graze over it in different ways.

Comment: General tip with doing multiple integrals: If the integrand looks impossible, try switching the order of integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I show you a simple trick or idea on how to invert the interval of a double integral.

**First step - Draw the integration area**

In this case we have $0< y <2$ and $y/2 < x < 1$, this is
[image]

**Second step - Calculate the inverses of the functions involved**

In this case we have $x = y/2$, then
$$
x = y/2 \Rightarrow y=2x 
$$

notice that $x = 1$ stays the same.

**Third step - Draw the inverses and find the new region**

[image]

but the question is, what is the region? The trick I have is to see where the original region is, we can see that the original region is attached to the $x$ axis, so the new region must be attached to the $x$ axis, that is

[image]

and stating this in double integral is easy

**Final step - Pose the integral**

$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2x} ycos(x^3 - 1) dydx
$$

and to see that everything is fine we enter everything into wolfram
[image]

[image]

just be careful with the axes and look at the dependent and independent variables

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!! You have no idea how much time and energy you have saved me with such a clean and precise explanation