Sum of two uniform random variable how to find integration limits
I'm trying to solve a problem that asks me to find me the p.d.f of $Y = X_1 + X_2$, where both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$. In order to do that I need to solve this:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X_1}(x) f_{X_2}(y-x) d x
$$
but I have trouble understanding how to find the limits of integration.
I know that $Y \in [0,2]$ and if I let $X_1 = x$, then $X_2 = y-x$. Then I think I have to solve two cases (but not sure why).
Case I: $0 \leq y \leq 1$
I think that I have to solve $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y-x \leq 1$
Case II: $1 \leq y \leq 2$.
It feels like there should be an easy way to do this, but I'm missing something essential that I need to proceed. I really don't understand how to approach finding the limits. I should note that I'm not great at working with inequalities, so that might be the reason why I am stuck.
Thankful for any advice.
EDIT
$X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d.

Meaningless question unless you have more information (like independence ) on $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Thanks. Added that they are i.i.d

Here another more simple and intuitive solution with a drawing. As you mentioned, we have $Y = X_1 + X_2$ and $X = X_1$. We original know $x_1,x_2 \in (0,1)^2$, then
\begin{align*}
0 & < x_1 < 1 \\
x_1 & < x_1 + x_2 < 1+x_1 \\
0 & <  x_1 < x_1 + x_2 < 1+ x_1 \\
0 & <  x < y < 1+ x
\end{align*}
with $x_1 = x \in (0,1)$, this region is

now, we are interesting in the variable $y$, then, by "turning" the axles  you have

then, if $y \in (0,1) \to x \in (0,y)$, and if $y \in (1,2) \to x \in (y-1,1)$. And finally, to found $f_Y(y)$ we need to split de interval.
Case 1 - $y \in (0,1)$:
\begin{align*}
f_Y(y) & = \int_{0}^{y}1 dx = y
\end{align*}
Case 2 - $y \in (1,2)$:
\begin{align*}
f_Y(y) & = \int_{y-1}^{1} 1 dx = 2-y
\end{align*}
Finally
$$
f_Y(y) = \begin{cases}
y, & 0 <y < 1 \\
2-y, & 1 < y < 2
\end{cases}
$$

Note: When I mean "turning" the axles, is to plot the area with the axes inverted, for this you need to calculate the inverses: \begin{align*} y & = x +1 \ x & = y-1 \end{align*} and \begin{align*} y & = x \ x & = y \end{align*}, now plot the region and recognize the previous region. For a similar idea you can see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4854476/inverting-the-order-of-integration/4854488#4854488

You cannot assume that any two random variables are independent.

bro, he wrote $f_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X_1}(x) f_{X_2}(y-x)dx$, not $f_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X_1,X_2}(x,y-x)dx$ Clearly in this step independence is assumed, why   much bad vibes for the post...

The safer way to do this may be to find the cdf $P(Y \le y)$ and then differentiate,
but with your approach of $$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X_1}(x_1) f_{X_2}(y-x_1) \, dx_1$$  with the supports of $X_1$ and $X_2$ restricted to $[0,1]$

this is clearly $0$ when $y \lt 0$ and when $y \gt 2$
when $0 \le y \le 1$ you would have $x_1>y$ requiring $x_2 < 0$, so it can be written as  $$\int_{0}^y f_{X_1}(x_1) f_{X_2}(y-x_1) \, dx_1$$
when $1 \le y \le 2$  you would have $x_1<y-1$ requiring $x_2 >1$, so it can be written as $$\int_{y-1}^1 f_{X_1}(x_1) f_{X_2}(y-x_1) \, dx_1$$

which you can combine as $$f_Y(y)= \int_{\max(0, y-1)}^{\min(1,y)} f_{X_1}(x_1) f_{X_2}(y-x_1) \, dx_1.$$
Since you have two uniform distributions, this is $\min(1,y)-\max(0, y-1)= |y-1|$ when $0 \le y \le 2$.

Thank you.  But as I tried to get across in the question, I am having difficulty understanding how to find the limits. For example, if $0 \leq y \leq 1$, why is $x_1 \geq y$? Maybe if I understand this I can understand the next limit. Sorry if this is super obvious, but I don't see it.

(Maybe its possible to make a sketch of Y to make it more intuitive...)

You cannot assume that any two random variables are independent.

@geetha290krm The convolution is the answer for the distribution of the sum when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, so your correct comment might better be aimed at the question.

@TomasR If $X_1 \le 1$ and $X_2 \ge 0$ and $Y=X_1+X_2$ then $X_1=Y-X_2 \le Y$ too, i.e. $X_1 \le \min(1,Y)$.  When $y \le 1$ this makes the upper limit $y$ for the integral over $x_1$, but when $y \ge 1$ this makes the upper limit $1$ for the integral over $x_1$.

Changing notation slightly, for all choices of fixed real number $z$,
\begin{align}f_Z(z) = f_{X+Y}(z) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(z-x) \, \mathrm dx\\  &= \int_{0}^1 f_X(x)f_Y(z-x) \, \mathrm dx & \text{since }f_X(x) = 0 \text{ when }x\notin [0,1]\\
&= \int_{0}^1 f_Y(z-x) \, \mathrm dx & \text{since }f_X(x) = 1 \text{ when }x\in [0,1].
\end{align}
Consider $4$ different possibilities for the fixed number $z$:
Case 1: $z < 0$.  As $x$ increases from $0$ to $1$, the value of the argument $z-x$ of the integrand $f_Y(z-x)$ is always less than $0$, and so the integrand is $0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Conclusion: $f_Z(z) = 0$ when $z < 0$.
Case 2: $z > 2$. As $x$ increases from $0$ to $1$, the value of the argument $z-x$ of the integrand $f_Y(z-x)$ is always greater than $1$, and so the integrand is $0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Conclusion: $f_Z(z) = 0$ when $z > 2$.
Case 3: $0 \leq z \leq 1$. Now, as $x$ increases from $0$ to $1$, the value of the argument $z-x$ of the integrand $f_Y(z-x)$ decreases from its initial value $z \in [0,1]$ when $x = 0$ to value $0$ when $x = z$ and goes negative as $x$ sweeps past $z$ on its way to $1$.  Thus, the integrand has value $1$ only for $x\in [0,z]$.  Conclusion: $f_Z(z) = z$ when $z \in [0,1].$
Case 4: $1 \leq z \leq 2$. Now, as $x$ increases from $0$ to $1$, the value of the argument $z-x$ of the integrand $f_Y(z-x)$ decreases from its initial value $z > 1$ when $x = 0$ to value $1$ when $x = z-1 \in [0,1]$ and continues to decrease to value $z-1 \in [0,1]$ when $x=1$.  Thus, the integrand has value $1$ only for $x\in [z-1,1]$, an interval of length $1-(z-1) = 2-z$.  Conclusion: $f_Z(z) = 2-z$ when $z \in [0,1].$
